# How to change order of list based on common element in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following list:

```
l1 = ['foo_x', 'bar_x', 'xyz_x', 'foo_y', 'bar_y', 'xyz_y']
```

I created a list with common elements.

```
l2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'xyz']

# trying to reorder which is not successful

[i for i in l1 if (l2 in l1)]
```

I would like to change the order of l1 to have the following outcome:

```
['foo_x', 'foo_y', 'bar_x', 'bar_y', 'xyz_x', 'xyz_y']
```

Comment: What is `foo_x` (and the others)? What is `foo`? Are these variables or are they actually strings and you have neglected to add quotes around them?

Comment: What are the elements? Are they sublists? Take a look at key= argument to `list.sort` and `sorted`. You might want to write a key function that takes index of that element in l1, but we cannot help further if we don't know what those are

Comment: Indeed they are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each element in `l1` is a superstring of *some* element in `l2`, you could use `next` to sort by the index of the first matching element.

```
>>> l1 = ['foo_x', 'bar_x', 'xyz_x', 'foo_y', 'bar_y', 'xyz_y']    
>>> l2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'xyz']
>>> sorted(l1, key=lambda x: next(i for i, e in enumerate(l2) if e in x))
['foo_x', 'foo_y', 'bar_x', 'bar_y', 'xyz_x', 'xyz_y']
```

The `next` means linear complexity (in size of `l2`) for each element in `l1`. If the `_` is significant, i.e. if the elements in `l2` are always the part before the `_`, you can create a dictionary mapping each element to its index and then look up that index directly using that substring.

```
>>> l2_idx = {e: i for i, e in enumerate(l2)}
>>> sorted(l1, key=lambda x: l2_idx[x[:x.index("_")]])
['foo_x', 'foo_y', 'bar_x', 'bar_y', 'xyz_x', 'xyz_y']
```

Both ways, in this form, would fail if there is no matching element in `l2`, but you can provide both with a default element to be used in that case, e.g. `len(l2)`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You need `.split()` then sort base index in `l2` and last part after `_` like below:

```
>>> l1 = ['foo_x', 'bar_x', 'xyz_x', 'foo_y', 'bar_y', 'xyz_y']

>>> l2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'xyz']

>>> sorted(l1, key=lambda x: (l2.index(x.split('_')[0]), x.split('_')[1]))
['foo_x', 'foo_y', 'bar_x', 'bar_y', 'xyz_x', 'xyz_y']
```

Another Example:

```
>>> l1 = ['foo_x', 'bar_x', 'xyz_x', 'foo_y', 'bar_y', 'xyz_y' , 'foo_a', 'bar_b', 'xyz_c']

>>> l2 = [ 'xyz' , 'foo', 'bar']

>>> sorted(l1, key=lambda x: (l2.index(x.split('_')[0]), x.split('_')[1]))
['xyz_c',
 'xyz_x',
 'xyz_y',
 'foo_a',
 'foo_x',
 'foo_y',
 'bar_b',
 'bar_x',
 'bar_y']
```